# В чем различие выводов сообщений?

Tags: javascript, html

Цель: вывести на экран сообщение в контейнере с `id="alert-container"`.
Написать можно по-разному:

```
var alertContainer = document.getElementById('alert-container');

alertContainer.innerHTML =
    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">' +
        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
        '<strong>Внимание! </strong>' + message +
    '</div>';
```

или

```
var alertContainer = document.getElementById('alert-container');

var alertDangerContainer = document.createElement('div');
alertDangerContainer.className = 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible';
alertDangerContainer.setAttribute('role', 'alert');

var buttonTimes = document.createElement('button');
buttonTimes.className = 'close';
buttonTimes.type = 'button';
buttonTimes.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'alert');
buttonTimes.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Close');

var spanButtonTimes = document.createElement('span');
spanButtonTimes.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
spanButtonTimes.innerHTML = '&times;';

buttonTimes.appendChild(spanButtonTimes);

var alertWarningStrong = document.createElement('strong');
alertWarningStrong.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Внимание! "));


alertDangerContainer.appendChild(buttonTimes);
alertDangerContainer.appendChild(alertWarningStrong);
alertDangerContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));

alertContainer.appendChild(alertDangerContainer);
```

Есть ли различие? Как лучше?

Comment: Различий особых нет. В первом случае есть опасность, что `message` может содержать небезопасные данные. Во втором случае вы можете легко добавить обработчики событий.

Comment: Лучше первый вариант, так как править легче. А еще лучше использовать шаблонизатор, например `ejs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Различий несколько, например, в первом примере содержимое `alertContainer` заменится полностью, во втором - добавится один элемент.

Но более глобальное отличие можно увидеть передав в message допустимую html разметку:

в первом случае она отобразиться как html, во втором - это будет обычный текст:

```js
function A1(message) {
  var alertContainer = document.getElementById('alert-container');

  alertContainer.innerHTML =
    '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">' +
    '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
    '<strong>Внимание! </strong>' + message +
    '</div>';
}

function A2(message) {

  var alertContainer = document.getElementById('alert-container');

  var alertDangerContainer = document.createElement('div');
  alertDangerContainer.className = 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissible';
  alertDangerContainer.setAttribute('role', 'alert');

  var buttonTimes = document.createElement('button');
  buttonTimes.className = 'close';
  buttonTimes.type = 'button';
  buttonTimes.setAttribute('data-dismiss', 'alert');
  buttonTimes.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Close');

  var spanButtonTimes = document.createElement('span');
  spanButtonTimes.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
  spanButtonTimes.innerHTML = '&times;';

  buttonTimes.appendChild(spanButtonTimes);

  var alertWarningStrong = document.createElement('strong');
  alertWarningStrong.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Внимание! "));


  alertDangerContainer.appendChild(buttonTimes);
  alertDangerContainer.appendChild(alertWarningStrong);
  alertDangerContainer.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));

  alertContainer.appendChild(alertDangerContainer);
}

A1('<b>bold text</b>');
A2('<b>bold text</b>');
```

```html
<div id="alert-container"></div>
```